# Jenkins Octopus Integration

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, octopus-deploy

I am using Jenkins as a CI tool and using Octopus to deploy my JAVA application. But when surfed, i could get solutions to deploy a .Net application using Octopack. But how to pack my JAVA Application and automatically deploy it into the Octopus server from my Jenkins instance?

Comment: is there any code written so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no code is needed. We have a JAVA application already present in GIT, fetched it from GIT, built it using Maven and now we need to deploy it to Octopus server.

Answer (score 1):

You can pack it with NuGet (with the `nuget pack` command, [documented here](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#package-authoring-commands)).  That's essentially all that Octopack does.  Create a `.nuspec` file, and in your `<files>` section, include the files you want with an empty target.  For example, this will include all files in your package:

```
...
<files>
    <file src="path/to/output/**" target="" />
</files>
...
```

You can then push it to your Octopus Deploy system using `nuget push`.  Instructions are on your Octopus Deploy Package Library page.

Comment: That is a command line activity we do. i am looking for automation. once the build in Jenkins is successful, the packaging has to happen and this package should be pushed to Octopus server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Jenkins does builds... can you run the commands as a post-build step?

Answer (score 1):

Since Octopus 3.3 you can also [package in tar and zip](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/supported-packages), in addition to NuGet.

You can configure the machine where you want your code to be deployed to as a [deployment target](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-targets). [Listening Tentacles](https://octopus.com/docs/installation/installing-tentacles/listening-tentacles) are the most oft-used ones.

Once your deployment target is configured, setup [Octo.exe](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/nuget-packages/using-octo.exe) on your Jenkins server and use the script console in your Jenkins job to automatically deploy your package to the intended target using Octo.exe .

You can also write the code to a script on the Jenkins server and call that directly from the console in the Jenkins job. We do this in our setup because Octo.exe uses the API-KEY which we'd rather keep secret from the developers.

Note: Octopus Deploy is also currently working on native Java support. See [this RFC](https://octopus.com/blog/java-rfc).